# OCR fails due to font specifics

Tags: c#, image, winforms, comparison, ocr

I have a library which contains all font characters (Arial in my case). For example:

[image]

I'm using this library to OCR text from image.

The problem is that **when you try to OCR such characters as "j", "/", "t" - characters could overlap one another!** So OCR is now impossible, because characters do not match pattern images (up to 3 pixels are different).

[image]

**How do I have to deal with this problem? Is there a better way to compare images? (C#, WinForms app)**

I'm using this method for comparison:

```
unsafe public static bool CompareMemCmp(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2)
    {
        if ((b1 == null) != (b2 == null)) return false;
        if (b1.Size != b2.Size) return false;

        var bd1 = b1.LockBits(new Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), b1.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bd2 = b2.LockBits(new Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), b2.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        try
        {
            IntPtr bd1scan0 = bd1.Scan0;
            IntPtr bd2scan0 = bd2.Scan0;

            int stride = bd1.Stride;
            int len = stride * b1.Height;

            return memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, len) == 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            b1.UnlockBits(bd1);
            b2.UnlockBits(bd2);
        }
    }
```

It's extremely fast and reliable.. but you cant get a result if condition from above is met.. unfortunately.

Comment: [So, it has come to this.](http://xkcd.com/1015/)

Comment: Your posted code simply compares images, it doesn't address the character recognition part at all. Depending on how you handle this, it isn't really a image comparison problem: For example you could compare combinations of characters to each other. But as an image problem, compare the individual pixels, not the entire image, and allow for some error criteria but still return a possible match. If you connect this to your char recognition function, you could allow more errors in characters that are often tightly kerned.

Comment: @JamieF The first step is to crop the character. The second step is to iterate through dictionary (dictionary<string, bitmap>) and return a value if condition image1=image2 is met. Then break the loop. That's my algorithm to do OCR.. but in reality it's much more complicated ;)

Comment: The typographical term for it is "kerning".  Standard in printed text, nowadays common in computer generated text as well.  You'll have to deal with it.  OCR is buy, not build.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, never heard of this term before. Do you know if it is  possible to generate all overlap (kerning) situations for a specific font?

Comment: For a specific font, yes.  Ligatures is another one you'll have to deal with btw.  The typical OCR challenge is that it can't accurately determine what font was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make these character pairs (there could be an unreasonable amount of them though..) "characters" ie. the "-j" combination would be recognized as "-j" character..

Comment: that's was my plan B.. but as you said, I can't possibly know all scenarios.. may be tens, may be thousands of combinations..

Answer (score 1):

You could return a score for each character. A kind of probability that the character is the character depicted.

You could make the score get higher if the center pixels match compared to edge pixels so you are able to make the guessing better.

Comment: **not sure what will happen with characters such as "u" and "ü".** The iteration through library stops when character is found, so, by this logic, the first letter that will be returned is "u" even if it's actually "ü" (because their scores are almost the same).

Comment: Then don't stop. Continue to make sure. As I suggested, you could return a list of characters ordered by probability.