# How to measure width of character precisely?

Tags: c#, .net, width, character

Maybe I've got something wrong, but... I want to simulate character spacing. 
I break the word (text) into the list of single characters, measure their widths, and then painting them one after another on the bitmap. I supposed, that overall width of the rendered text will be the same as the width of the whole not splitted string, but there is something wrong. Rendering characters in a loop show wider result. Is there any way to get common (expected) results?

here is a code snippet:

```
private struct CharWidths
{
    public char Char;
    public float Width;
}

private List<CharWidths> CharacterWidths = new List<CharWidths>();
```

...

```
private void GetCharacterWidths(string Text, Bitmap BMP)
{
    int i;
    int l = Text.Length;
    CharacterWidths.Clear();
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP);

    CharWidths cw = new CharWidths();
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text[i].ToString(), Font);
        cw.Char = Text[i];
        cw.Width = textSize.Width;
        CharacterWidths.Add(cw);
    }
}
```

...

```
public void RenderToBitmap(Bitmap BMP)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("color");

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP);
    GetCharacterWidths("Lyborko", BMP);

    int i;
    float X = 0;
    PointF P = new PointF(); 
    for (i = 0; i < CharacterWidths.Count; i++)
    {
        P.X = X;
        P.Y = 0;

        g.DrawString(CharacterWidths[i].Char.ToString(), Font, Brushes.White, P);

        X = X+CharacterWidths[i].Width;
    }

    P.X = 0;
    P.Y = 30;
    g.DrawString("Lyborko", Font, Brushes.White, P);
    // see the difference
}
```

Thanx a lot

Comment: Your approach is pretty much doomed once you get to "unusual" characters. For example there are combining characters, where several codepoints are rendered as a single symbol on the screen. Your code also splits the text into UTF-16 codeunits, not codepoints.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Ok, it is surely not the best of, but what should I do?

Comment: This question demonstrates well why this doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9945972/17034  Measure strings, not characters.

Answer (score 2):

First of all should say that don't have a silver bullet solution for this, but have a couple of suggessions on subject:

1. Considering that you by calling `TextRenderer.MeasureText` do not pass current `device context` (the same one you use to draw a string after) and knowing a simple fact that `MeasureText` simply in case of lack of that parameter creates a new one compatible with desktop and calls `DrawTextEx` WindowsSDK function, I would say first use an overload of [MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc0wd5x6.aspx) where you specify like a first argument `device context` which you use to render a text after. *Could* make a difference.
2. If it fails, I would *try* to use [Control.GetPreferredSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getpreferredsize.aspx) method to *guess* most presize possible rendering dimension of the control on the screen, so *actually* the dimension of you future string's bitmap. To do that you can create some temporary control, assign a string, render and after call this function. It's clear to me that *this* solution may hardly fit in your app architecture, but *can* possibly produce a better results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to specify DeviceContext as you proposed: 
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, Text[i].ToString(), Font); 
but no change occured...

Comment: @lyborko: and what about second option ?

Comment: the second option I didn't tried. I have got remarkable results by setting TextFlags, but still, the difference is visible (in pixel though). See : TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;
                Size si = new Size(1, 1);
                Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, Text[i].ToString(), Font, si, flags);